# Why Flask Migrate doesn't create an empty migration file?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I am using Flask, Flask-SqlAlchemy and Flask-Migrate to manage my models. And I just realize that in my latest database state, when I create a new migration file, `python manage.py db migrate -m'test migration`, it will not create an empty migration file. Instead it tries to create and drop several unique key and foreign key constraints.

Any ideas why it behaves like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have made no changes to your model from the current migration, but you get a non-empty migration file generated, then it suggests for some reason your models became out of sync with the database, and the contents of this new migration are just the things that are mismatched.

If you say that the migration contains code that drops some constraints and add some other ones, it makes me think that the constraint names have probable changed, or maybe you upgraded your SQLAlchemy version to a newer version that generates constraints with different names.

Comment: Hi @miguel, thank you for your reply! Hm, at the moment I am not that sure why my migration create a non empty migration. SqlAlchemy version still the same (Flask-SqlAlchemy 2.1). And no model changes (that directly related to the aforementioned constraints). I am accepting this non empty migration files, and I see that subsequent migration does empty. I will check whether this solution acceptable in my case

Comment: Your solution may work, but be sure to test generating a brand new database and running it through the entire migration list, making sure this non-empty migration does not fail for a database made from scratch.

Comment: Just want to let you know, that I create that pre existing migration, and successfully create next migration after that. Although I am not sure what create that error in the first place. Although, the database was Backup and later Restore using PostgreSQL. Was just thinking that the process change some index name...